# loading md2 in android appears as white color

Tags: android

I am new to 3d animation in android. I tried to load a md2 object from [min3d example](http://code.google.com/p/min3d/).

But it animates as white colored.
 My source code is below

```
@Override
    public void initScene() {
        scene.lights().add(new Light());
        IParser parser = Parser.createParser(Parser.Type.MD2,
                getResources(), "net.mygame:raw/ogro", true);
        parser.parse();
        ogre = parser.getParsedAnimationObject();
        ogre.scale().x = ogre.scale().y = ogre.scale().z = .07f;
        ogre.rotation().z = -90;
        ogre.rotation().x = -90;
        scene.addChild(ogre);
        ogre.setFps(70);
        ogre.play();
    }
```

If anyone experienced the same problem or do u know solution, help me to come across this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search i found the solution myself. I forgot to add texture image in drawable folder. When i added it, got the animation which was perfect.